# C++ Restoring a window using ShowWindow disables its minimize capability

Tags: c++, winapi

I am having a problem while keeping only one instance of window running.

**Implementation details:** I have a C++ application which displays as an icon in the taskbar. On double-clik of the icon I am opening a new delphi window using ShellExecuteW function. Now I have implemented a logic that whenever user double-clicks the icon, it only opens one instance of the window, avoiding launching multiple windows. If the user double-clicks the icon, and if there is already a window open, it will just bring the window to the front, or if it is minimized it will restore the window.

Below code shows how I have implemented the above logic, it is triggered when the icon is double-clicked:

```
///////////////////////Double Click Code starts/////////////////////////
HWND hWnd = NULL;
HWND hWndFirst = NULL;
DWORD dw = FindProcessId("abc.exe");
if(dw == 0)
{
  //Open new window
  ShellExecuteW(0, L"open", acExePath, acParams, acFullPath, SW_SHOW);
  hWndFirst = NULL;
}
else
{
  //Open existing window
  hWnd = hGetWindowHandleOfProcess(dw);
  if(hWndFirst == NULL) hWndFirst = hWnd;

  if(hWndFirst != hWnd)
  {
    //This is just a small work-around as minimizing the window was changing
    //it's window handle. So I preserve the window handle the first time and 
    //use it whenever the window is minimized (i.e. the handle is changed)
    SetForegroundWindow(hWndFirst);
    ShowWindow(hWndFirst, SW_RESTORE);
  }
  else
  {
    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_RESTORE);
  }
}
///////////////////////Double Click Code ends///////////////////////////

///////////////////////Supporting functions/////////////////////////
struct ProcessHandleData
{
    unsigned long lProcessId;
    HWND hProcessWindowHandle;
};
//Finds the process id when given the process name
DWORD FindProcessId(char* pcProcessName)
{
    char* pcBegin = strrchr(pcProcessName, '\\');
    if(pcBegin)
        pcProcessName = pcBegin+1;

    PROCESSENTRY32 sProcessInfo;
    sProcessInfo.dwSize = sizeof(sProcessInfo);

    HANDLE sProcessesSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
    if ( sProcessesSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
        return 0;

    Process32First(sProcessesSnapshot, &sProcessInfo);
    if ( !strcmp(pcProcessName, sProcessInfo.szExeFile) )
    {
        CloseHandle(sProcessesSnapshot);
        return sProcessInfo.th32ProcessID;
    }

    while ( Process32Next(sProcessesSnapshot, &sProcessInfo) )
    {
        if ( !strcmp(pcProcessName, sProcessInfo.szExeFile) )
        {
          CloseHandle(sProcessesSnapshot);
          return sProcessInfo.th32ProcessID;
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(sProcessesSnapshot);
    return 0;
}

//Search predicate for EnumWindows function    
BOOL CALLBACK bEnumWindowsSearcher(HWND handle, LPARAM lParam)
{
    ProcessHandleData& sProcesshandleData = *(ProcessHandleData*)lParam;
    unsigned long lProcessId = 0;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, &lProcessId);
    if (sProcesshandleData.lProcessId != lProcessId)
      return true;
    sProcesshandleData.hProcessWindowHandle = handle;
    return false;
}

//Gets the window handle of the process (input process id)
HWND hGetWindowHandleOfProcess(unsigned long lProcessId)
{
    ProcessHandleData sProcessHandleData;
    sProcessHandleData.lProcessId = lProcessId;
    sProcessHandleData.hProcessWindowHandle = 0;
    EnumWindows(bEnumWindowsSearcher, (LPARAM)&sProcessHandleData);  //enumerate all windows
    return sProcessHandleData.hProcessWindowHandle;
}
```

**Problem:**
The above code works properly. But there is one problem that I am facing. If the open window is not active or behind any window, the above code brings it to the front ( as expected). But if I minimize the window and double click the icon, it restores the window and brings it to the front (again as expected). But after this action, I am no more able to minimize the window using the minimize bar at the top right corner of the window. Something disables(not physically) the minimize bar of the window.

Ay help would be greatly appreciated in this regard. Please let me know if you need more information with respect to the problem.

Many thanks.

PS: The above code is not entirely mine, I have researched various websites to get the code for various parts of the problem running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of the problem is that you are restoring the previous window from within the wrong process in the wrong manner.  By doing it the way you are, the previous window's state gets out of sync, that is why minimize stops working.

Instead, design your app so that the new instance can send a custom window message (or any other form of IPC of your choosing) to the previous instance, and in response to that message the previous instance can use `Application->Restore()` and `SetForegroundWindow()` to restore itself properly.

Also, your whole process enumeration logic is just plain overkill.

Try something more like this instead:

```
const UINT uiMyMsg = RegisterWindowMessage(TEXT("MY_RESTORE_MSG"));
...

if (!FindProcessId("abc.exe"))
{
    //Open new window
    ShellExecuteW(0, L"open", acExePath, acParams, acFullPath, SW_SHOW);
}
else
{
    if (uiMyMsg != 0)
        PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, uiMyMsg, 0, 0);
}
```

Then inside of `abc.exe`, do something like this:

```
const UINT uiMyMsg = RegisterWindowMessage(TEXT("MY_RESTORE_MSG"));

__fastcall TMainForm::TMainForm(TComponent *Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    Application->HookMainWindow(&AppHook);
}

__fastcall TMainForm::~TMainForm()
{
    Application->UnhookMainWindow(&AppHook);
}

bool __fastcall TMainForm::AppHook(TMessage &Message)
{
    if ((Message.Msg == uiMyMsg) && (uiMyMsg != 0))
    {
        ShowMe();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void __fastcall TMainForm::WndProc(TMessage &Message)
{
    if ((Message.Msg == uiMyMsg) && (uiMyMsg != 0))
        ShowMe();
    else
        TForm::WndProc(Message);
}

void __fastcall TMainForm::ShowMe()
{
    Application->Restore();
    if (WindowState == wsMinimized)
        WindowState = wsNormal;
    Show();
    SetForegroundWindow(Handle);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Remy, however in Delphi abc.exe the RegisterWindowMessage is returning negative value. I am currently investigating why is it happening.

Comment: `RegisterWindowMessage()` returns an `unsigned int`, so it **cannot** return a negative value.  Make sure you are assigning the value to a `UINT` or at least a `LongWord`, not an `Integer`.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out. Once again thanks for providing such a clean solution.